# Java-Swing adding multiple lines in jtable's cell

Tags: java, html, swing, jtable, multiline

i would like to insert multiple strings in the same cell in a jtable line by line.This is the way i added the data into jtable

```
       String Model,Brand,Serial;

       String itemdetails=Model+Brand+Serial

       model.addRow(new Object[]{itemdetails,amountText.getText()});
```

Here what the problem is,getting the output in single line,But i want output like this in a jtbale's cell.

```
      Model                    //it is string coming from database
      Brand                      //it is string coming from database
      Serial                   //it is string coming from database
```

i have tried this but its working only data within double quotes,not with strings.

```
                  "<html>lineOne <br/> lineTwo </html>"
```

Comment: I think you will need to adjust the row height manually.  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responsesrunnable example

Comment: yeah before i adjust the row height i need to get output in multiple lines.What will i do for that sir.

Comment: Is the HTML you've added to you question the data in the `TableModel` or do you use a custom `TableCellRederer`?

Comment: iam using normal DefaultTableModel.

Comment: Okay, but when does `<html>lineOne <br/> lineTwo </html>` get generated?  When you put into model or because you have a custom `TableCelLRenderer` doing it?

Comment: No sir.I implemented directly.How can i do that with TableCellRender.Iam a beginner.

Comment: I don't think you really need to, but have a look [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, without doing anything special, I can make `<html>...<br>...</html>` work just fine...

[image: Multilines]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 1);
            model.addRow(new String[]{
                "<html>My teacher took my iPod.<br>She said they had a rule;<br>I couldn't bring it into class<br>or even to the school.</html>"
            });
            model.addRow(new String[]{
                "<html>She said she would return it;<br>I'd have it back that day.<br>But then she tried my headphones on<br>and gave a click on Play.</html>"
            });
            model.addRow(new String[]{
                "<html>She looked a little startled,<br>"
                + "but after just a while<br>"
                + "she made sure we were occupied<br>"
                + "and cracked a wicked smile.<br>"
            });
            model.addRow(new String[]{
                "<html>Her body started swaying.<br>"
                + "Her toes began to tap.<br>"
                + "She started grooving in her seat<br>"
                + "and rocking to the rap.</html>"
            });
            model.addRow(new String[]{
                "<html>My teacher said she changed her mind.<br>"
                + "She thinks it's now okay<br>"
                + "to bring my iPod into class.<br>"
                + "She takes it every day.</html>"
            });

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            table.setRowHeight(75);
            add(new JScrollPane(table));

        }

    }

}
```

Maybe there's something else in your code, which you're not showing us, which is causing the problem...

> Updated with "dynamic" example

This is going past the original question, BUT, the `TableModel` represents the data it's backing, it provides the structure for the `JTable` to show it.

So, given a bunch of "disconnected" values, it's the `TableModel` which is going to "sew" them together, based on your requirements.

The following example simple splits each line of the previous poem in a an array, when each line represents a element.

This is then wrapped again so each section of the poem is an array of lines...

```
String data[][] = {
            {"My teacher took my iPod.", "She said they had a rule;", "I couldn't bring it into class", "or even to the school."},
            {"She said she would return it;", "I'd have it back that day.", "But then she tried my headphones on", "and gave a click on Play."}, 
            etc...
```

The example then uses a custom `TableModel`, which when asked for the value of the cell, takes the given "section" and builds a `String` out of each line, wrapping into a `<html>` based `String`.

Further, you need to click the Add button to add each new line before it can be displayed

[image: Dynamic data]

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private MyTableModel model;
    private int index = 0;
    public TestPane() {
        String data[][] = {
            {"My teacher took my iPod.", "She said they had a rule;", "I couldn't bring it into class", "or even to the school."},
            {"She said she would return it;", "I'd have it back that day.", "But then she tried my headphones on", "and gave a click on Play."},
            {"She looked a little startled,", "but after just a while", "she made sure we were occupied", "and cracked a wicked smile.", ""},
            {"Her body started swaying.", "Her toes began to tap.", "She started grooving in her seat", "and rocking to the rap."},
            {"My teacher said she changed her mind.", "She thinks it's now okay", "to bring my iPod into class.", "She takes it every day."}
        };

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        model = new MyTableModel();

        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setRowHeight(75);
        add(new JScrollPane(table));

        JButton add = new JButton("Add");
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (index < data.length) {
                    model.addRow(data[index]);
                }
                index++;
                if (index >= data.length) {
                    add.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });

        add(add, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<String[]> rowData;

        public MyTableModel() {
            rowData = new ArrayList<>(25);
        }

        public void addRow(String[] data) {
            rowData.add(data);
            fireTableRowsInserted(rowData.size() - 1, rowData.size() - 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Object value = null;
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    String[] data = rowData.get(rowIndex);
                    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("<br>", "<html>", "</html>");
                    for (String text : data) {
                        joiner.add(text);
                    }
                    value = joiner.toString();
                    break;
            }
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return rowData.size();
        }

    }

}
```

Take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: yeah this is exactly true but my variables are non static.means it will change dynamically.when we write a string inside double  quotes it will always static.But my model and brand may vary time by time. So what will i do.

Comment: Nothing, it won't make any difference, you can change the contents of the model or the model itself and it won't make any difference

Comment: Consider my model=dualcore processor and brand=intel ,but i cannot put them within doublequotes directly.because it may vary next time(Here iam creating billing system).When we put them within double quotes we should change the content always.But i says Model and Brand are two variables that may change dynamically.

Comment: Have your `TableModel` generate the value for the cell from the data it's backing

Comment: It's not filling my TableModel at  begning.Consider in billing system what we will do,first we will search a product,and then we will add it to the table for printing purpose.if we want second item to add we will add like that.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  As you add data to the table model, the model would then use the `getValueAt` method to determine what values go into what cell.  You've not provided enough context to your original question to really define an exact solution

Comment: Sir,Consider my variable Medel holding items={intel,asus,mercury},so can u tell me how we can access write them within html tags without writing directly like this model.addRow(new String[]{
                "<html>intel.<br>"
                + "asus<br>"
                + "mercury.<br>"
           </html>"
            });

Comment: i mean i need to get them by using the variable model,but suppose if we wrote like this model.addRow(new String[]{
                "<html>Model.<br>"
                + "Brand<br>"
               </html>"
            });,the output will be always model and always brand,it will not change,beacause we put the variable model and brand within double quotes,and its became constant.

Comment: Take a look at the update. Personally, you can't rely on `DefaultTableModel` to do it for.  For that, you would need to preformat each column value the way you wanted it.  A custom `TableModel` will allow you to model the data anyway you want and have the `TableModel` translate for the `JTable`

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is incorrectly close :

```
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jt.getModel();
    int i; 
    for(i=0; i<model.getRowCount(); i++){ 
    String itemdetails=model+"\n"+brand; 
    System.out.println(itemdetails);
    jt.setRowHeight(30);
    model.addRow(new Object[]{i+1,itemdetails,amountText.getText()}); }
```

Comment: its working with System.out.println(itemdetails);.But still output getting in single line in jtable's cell.

Comment: can you provide your main class that contain this code

Comment: DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jt.getModel();
                int i;
                for(i=0; i<model.getRowCount(); i++){
                    {}
                }
                
                String itemdetails=model+"\n"+brand;
               
                System.out.println(itemdetails);
                  jt.setRowHeight(30);
            
                model.addRow(new Object[]{i+1,itemdetails,amountText.getText()});
              
    }