# How to display complex object to single JTable cell?

Tags: java, swing

I have Object OrderProduct with fields: value, count and name. I would like to display whole order which contains many orderproducts. My idea is to display orderporducts like this:

___________________
|Name count: x value y|
|Name count: x value y|
|Name count: x value y|

but i can't put new line. I have something like this:

```
public String listOfOPToString() {
    String string = "";
    for(OrdersProducts x : listOfProductsInOrder){
        string = string + x + "\n";
    }
    return string;
}
```

Maybe there is a better way to put that? Like comboBox or sth.
All I have now is: 
[image]

Comment: Use a custom `TableCellRender` and wrap the content into `<html>` tags.  As an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042605/java-swing-adding-multiple-lines-in-jtables-cell/31043203#31043203)

Comment: can you show your object classes?

Comment: @MadProgrammer It worked, thanks. I have another question, can I set row height according to number of products? For example in first row i have 2 products so I would like 2xdefault height in second row i would like 3xdefault row? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but it's much more difficult, as you will need to know, for each row, not the number of "lines" it will generate, but how high each cell will be.

Comment: Maybe better solution is to use JTextArea, so it can be scrolled if it will be to high.

Comment: Not really, apart from some additional line/word wrapping.  The problem there is the cell is not actually "alive", it's just rubber stamped onto the table (it's just painted), so the components not respond to user input.  You could make the cell "editable", but then adds a bunch of additional complexity...

Comment: I followed this tutorial: [link]http://esus.com/embedding-a-jtextarea-in-a-jtable-cell/ and I have JtextArea but html stopped working EDIT: now \n is working :) Thanks for your help