# Swing wrap text in a table's cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextarea

I want to render a `JTable` component's cell to support line wrapping, so I am using a `JTextarea` inside the cell, because text area allows line wrapping. This is my code:

```
//Render column with header Person
table.getColumn("Person").setCellRenderer(new RenderRedGreen());


final class RenderRedGreen extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    JTextArea textarea;

      @Override public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable aTable, Object aNumberValue, boolean aIsSelected, 
        boolean aHasFocus, int aRow, int aColumn ) 
      {  
         String value = (String)aNumberValue;

         textarea = new JTextArea();
         aTable.add(textarea);
         textarea.setLineWrap(true);
         textarea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

          textarea.setText(value);
         aTable.setRowHeight(90);

        if (aNumberValue == null) return this;

        Component renderer = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                aTable, aNumberValue, aIsSelected, aHasFocus, aRow, aColumn
        );


        if (value.equals("Me")) 
          renderer.setForeground(Color.red);
        else
            renderer.setForeground(Color.black);

        return this;
      }
}
```

The problem is that the text is not wrapped, so I can not see long texts completely. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Generally, wrapping text isn't the hard part, you could just wrap the text in `<html>` tags and it would wrap, the problem is going to be making the row large enough to actually fit the text (by the way, don't set the row height in the renderer, that's not it's job). The problem is, you seem to be trying to setup the `JTextArea` and some other render but are simply passing back `this` ... so what does that have to do with the `JTextArea`?

Comment: As an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042605/java-swing-adding-multiple-lines-in-jtables-cell/31043203#31043203)

Comment: `new JTextArea();` should be more like `new JTextArea(3,20); //suggest size!`

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I think you can use DefaultTableCellRender wrapping text with `<html>` tags. And JTextArea can be used as a EditorComponent instead of using it as renderer component.

Answer (score 0):

These lines of code would help you to wrap the data and show multiple lines properly :

```
    textarea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textarea.setLineWrap(true);
    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textarea.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);
```