# Newline (\n) is not working by using AbstractTableModel for JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, newline, tablecellrenderer

I need to have multiple lines in one table column. I have given `\r\n` in between the `String`. But new line is not coming. I have tried with `\n`, `System.lineSeparator()` and `line.separator`. Nothing is working.

My output should allow multiple lines in each cell.

My Code shows as below:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

class AppSwing extends AbstractTableModel {



  public Object[][] values = {
      { "C\r\n\r\nAfterNewLine", "A\r\n\r\n" },
     };

  public int getRowCount() {
    return values.length;
  }

  public int getColumnCount() {
    return values[0].length;
  }

  public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    return values[row][column];
  }
}
```

Main class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;

class App extends JFrame {

protected JTable table;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    App stt = new App();
    stt.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    stt.setSize(400, 200);
    stt.setVisible(true);
  }

  public App() {
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    AppSwing tv = new AppSwing();
    table = new JTable(tv);
    pane.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }

}
```

Result--

CAfterNewLine     A

Comment: The first thing you're going to want to look at [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Using Custom Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer).  It's unlikely that `JLabel` will support new lines in this fashion, but it does support html (all be it limited to v3.2) - [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042605/java-swing-adding-multiple-lines-in-jtables-cell/31043203#31043203)

Comment: v3.2 is HTML version?

Comment: Yes ... and limited CSS support, so don't expect anything fancy

Comment: First of all, Swing supports HTML, always has.  Second of all, I've already linked one example which demonstrates the concept, have you tried it?

Comment: Yeah. With StringJoiner its working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try String Joiner as below example.

```
 String[] data = rowData.get(rowIndex);
                    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("<br>", "<html>", "</html>");
                    for (String text : data) {
                        joiner.add(text);
                    }
                    value = joiner.toString();
```